# Rep notifications for Teams posts not being delivered

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, achievements-dialog

Since approximately June 15th, I have not received any notifications in the top bar for Teams rep gains (upvotes and accepts).

Inbox notifications such as comments from the Team seem to be unaffected, but I neither receive the green rep notification in the top bar or any record of reputation change in the dropdown when clicking the achievements icon. The rep is still recorded as expected in the reputation tab of my profile.

Is this an intended change, or is there a bug with rep notification delivery?

Comment: Looks solved now, I just got +80 from Teams upvotes over a period of 2-3 days.